# How to add success mesage on click of add to cart buttton in custom module in Magento 2

Tags: custom, addtocart, magento2.3.5-p1, global-messages, success-message

I want to display success message on click of add to cart button in magento 2.

I am developing custom module in which i can develop functionality of add to cart and i want to  add success and error messages on click of add to cart in Magento 2.

so anyone can have idea then please share with me.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages can be displayed by using the MessageManager.

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Cart;

class Cart extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_messageManager;
    
    public function __construct
    (
       \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
       \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
    )
    {
       $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
       
       parent::__construct($context);
    }
     
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Item Added to Cart Successfully.'));
        
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
    }
}
```

You can use your custom module to overwrite the add to cart action/template and display a message with MessageManager.